# Regex Not Working For Some String

Tags: regex

These two strings seem to be the same. Why would regex match one but not another?

```
$str1 = "NЕТ";
$str2 = "NET";
if (preg_match("/NET/",$str1)){
    echo "Match string 1!";
}
else {
    echo "Does not match string 1!";
}
if (preg_match("/NET/",$str2)){
    echo "Match string 2!";
}
else {
    echo "Does not match string 2!";
}
```

Output:

```
Does not match string 1!Match string 2!
```

Comment: `!` how can u miss !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What is the output from that?

Comment: Where should I add it?

Comment: In your question. Click the small "edit" link just below the post.

Comment: "/NET/" matches the first string but not the second

Comment: you add ! in second if statement

Comment: That's my point. The regex does not match the second string.

Comment: @Justin, if you replace `$str2` with `$str1` in your second statement, the output will be same. `$str2` and `$str1` are identical, but your comparison statements are not.

Comment: What is the _actual_ output when you run your code?

Comment: It looks like your "E" and "T" from the first string are not what they seem...

Comment: You should post this on puzzling.stackexchange too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spoiler alert:** `$str1` and `$str2` are **NOT** identical.

It's because the characters, while they look the same, are actually different:

```
$str1 = "NЕТ"; echo bin2hex($str1), "\n";
$str2 = "NET"; echo bin2hex($str2), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
4ed095d0a2
4e4554
```

Indeed, if you print out all of the names of the characters in each string along with their Unicode code points, you'll get the first block for `$str1` and the second block for `$str2`.

```
78 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
1045 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IE
1058 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER TE

78 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
69 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
84 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
```

Comment: Ah, was not aware Java's Character had that ability. Thank you.